# Why these two paths are homotopic?

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

Why are these two paths (i.e. the red and the black) homotopic :

[image]

Because we cannot break continuously the loop, can we ? Indeed, to take off the loop, we have to cut the path somewhere and then glue it again to get the red path. So we cannot get the red path by deforming continuously the black path, do we ?

Same question if one path has a knot :

[image]

It's says that both path are homotopic, but we have the same problem, we can not get a line without cutting somewhere. So we cannot get the red path by deforming continuously the black path, do we ?

If yes, I really don't get this things of homotopy.

Comment: The space "inside" the loop is solid, so you can draw it to a close and get rid of it.  Different story if there is an interior hole preventing this.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it... we cannot break the loop like this... if yes, why ? (I follow a manifold course and it was always the problem of : "deforming continuously or not a curve to get an other curve". Here typically we can not. @Randall

Comment: You look to make confusion between *homeomorphic* and *homotopic*. It's exactly your example : in both of your draws, the red path and the black path **are** *homotopic*, but they **are not** *homeomorphic*.

Comment: @user386627  It could help you greatly if you go to the definitions and prove that any two paths in $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{R}^2$ if you want) based at, say, $0$ and $1$ are always homotopic to each other.  It's a good first step to understanding your issue.

Comment: Instead of thinking path as rope, it may be useful to think it as "ray of light". With this notion, you can definitely continuously get the red path from the black path.

Comment: @Randall: Let $(x(t),y(t))$ and $(s(t),m(t))$ two path of $\mathbb R^2$ that start at $0$ and end at $1$. Set $k(t)=Proj_{x}(x(t),y(t))=x(t)$ and $h(t)=proj_{x}(s(t),m(t))=s(t)$ then $\{h(t)\mid t\in [0,1]\}=\{k(t)\mid t\in [0,1]\}$ are two path from $0$ to $1$ and $h$ and $k$ are continuous. Does it work ?

Comment: OK, it seems like you don't have the definition of homotopy.  Given (Euclidean) paths $\alpha$ and $\beta$, define $H(x,t) = (1-t)\alpha(x) + t\beta (x)$.  Then $H$ is a homotopy from $\alpha$ to $\beta$ showing they are homotopic.

Comment: Does the animation here not help?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy

Comment: @Randall: Yes thank you :) But it was with path with loop that I had a misunderstanding. But I think that representation as Ray of light helps a lot too.

Comment: @Randall: in case where the path can be parametrized, my proof is still wrong ? Because it looks correct for me in fact.

Comment: Yes, it is incorrect.